# LibGdx-ViewPort width and height does not match for some devices

Tags: java, android, libgdx, viewport

I am using a Viewport for my libGdx landscape game like this.

```
public static final int WORLD_WIDTH = 1280;
public static final int WORLD_HEIGHT = 800;

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
float aspectRatio = Constants.WORLD_WIDTH / Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT; 

ViewPort viewPort = new FillViewport(WORLD_WIDTH * aspectRatio,WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
```

I am using all positions in terms of this width and height.

It is working fine in all devices except device that have screen resolution greater than 1300.
In device that have greater resolution than 1300,only middle part of the game is visible.I tried using stretched viewport for the greater resolution device,but it is giving all game elements stretched.

How can I make my game working in all devices fine?Do I need to change the viewport?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I made it work. I am not sure whether this is the correct way to solve such problems.
I did it like this;

```
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    if(screenHeight>1300)
    {

        Constants.WORLD_WIDTH=1280;
        Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT=960;

    }
    else{
        Constants.WORLD_WIDTH=1280;
        Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT=800;

    }
     viewPort = new FillViewport(Constants.WORLD_WIDTH, Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
     viewPort.apply();
```

I used a viewPort width of 1280x960 for all greater resolution devices while keeping 1280x800 resolution for all other devices that has screen width less than 1300.
While drawing background I used viewport width and height to set the size like this.

```
bgSprite=new Sprite(bgTexture);
    bgSprite.setPosition(Constants.BG_X,Constants.BG_Y);
bgSprite.setSize(game.viewPort.getWorldWidth(),game.viewPort.getWorldHeight());
```

Not sure this the right way,but doing this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend [ExtendViewprot](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#extendviewport) to use, because it keeps the world aspect ratio without black bars by extending the world in one direction. Use all positions in terms of world width and height not screen width and height and resize viewport in resize method according to your device width and height.

Your resources size should be in the respect of world width and height.

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Stage stage;
    public static final int WORLD_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int WORLD_HEIGHT = 480;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        ExtendViewport extendViewport=new ExtendViewport(WORLD_WIDTH,WORLD_HEIGHT);
        stage=new Stage(extendViewport);

        //logical pixels of your current device, device specific
        //float w=Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); //screen width
        //float h=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();// screen height

        Image image=new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
        image.setPosition(WORLD_WIDTH/2,WORLD_HEIGHT/2, Align.center);  //consider world width and height instead of screen width and height

        stage.addActor(image);
        stage.setDebugAll(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

        stage.getViewport().update(width,height);
        stage.getCamera().position.set(WORLD_WIDTH/2,WORLD_HEIGHT/2,0);
        stage.getCamera().update();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried extend viewport.It does not show any black bars but still some portion of screen is going out.background is a static one in my game.I specified all positions in terms of world_width and world_height only.

Comment: what do you mean by static background ? you must resize viewport of stage and you should create your backgound in the dimension of 800*480 becasue it is your world width and height.

Comment: I am using a fixed resolution of 1280*800 with FillViewPort.The problem I am having is with the buttons that used to be at the edge of the screen. Those buttons are going out of screen.When I use extend viewport also,problem persists.All elements need to be fit inside the screen coordinates according to the device resolution.But this is not happening for tab device(tab has screen width>1300)