# LIBGDX font different positions on different platform

Tags: java, android, libgdx

When I run the android version of my app, the text that is drawn using Bitmap is displayed in a (way) different position in my desktop version than in my android version of the app. I have already looked this issue up and read that I had to set the Projectmatrix to combined, but this hasn't helped. No clue what could be the reason that it displays the texts in different positions crossplatform-wise.

```
public class HighScoresScreen implements Screen{

    private CrossplatformApp game;
    private Stage stage;
    private TextButton backButton;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Table table;
    BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();
    private Skin skin;
    private Texture background;
    private String[] data;
    private String[] playerscores;
    String nm = "";
    String sc = "";

    public HighScoresScreen (CrossplatformApp game) {
        this.game = game;
        this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT);
        this.camera.position.set(Constants.WIDTH/2, Constants.HEIGHT/2, 0);
        this.camera.update();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(this.camera.combined);
        this.skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin/uiskin.json"));
        this.background = new Texture("Screens/HighscoresScreen/highscores.png");
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {

        backButton = new TextButton("back", skin);
        backButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
                MenuScreen.musicHandler.stopMusic();
            }
        });

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        JSONfunctions json = new JSONfunctions();
        parseJSON parse = new parseJSON(json.doInBackground());

        for (String i : parse.getNames()){
            if(i != null) {
                nm += i;
                nm += "\n\n";
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(nm);
//
        for (String i : parse.getScores()){
            if(i != null) {
                sc += i;
                sc += "\n\n";
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        table = new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.bottom();
        table.add(backButton).size(100, 100);
        stage.addActor(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        font.draw(game.batch, nm, 100, 300);
        font.draw(game.batch, sc, 480, 300);

        game.batch.end();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using viewports ?

Comment: @Expiredmind yes I have, like this: `this.camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        this.stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(Constants.WIDTH, Constants.HEIGHT, camera));` and then draw this stage in the render method

Comment: I think you can use `Label` and then add it into the stage.Then you can remove the  `font.draw`.  The `viewport` in the stage can handle diffrent resolution quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update viewport of camera and then update projectionmatrix of `SpriteBatch` with updated viewport.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
}
```

Also you need to update Stage's viewport with screen with and height.

You should use `Label` for `nm` and `sc` text.

It's better to use `ExtendViewprot` instead of `FillViewport`, take a look of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43731930/3445320) answer.