# How can I implement a ScreenViewport?

Tags: android, libgdx, viewport

I'm new to libgdx and I have a question:

How can I implement a ScreenViewport? I created a new class but I think that is not enough. I'm developing a game and therefore I need the viewport so that every device is gets supported.

I also developed a score but without a viewport the texture will be on different positions on the screen. However, I want it on a certain position!
Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

World size of `ScreenViewport` is based on the size of the screen so for different screen size, you'll get different world size.

You should take a look of libgdx [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports), and choose appropriate viewport for your requirement.

I'll recommend you to use `ExtendViewport` because it keeps the world aspect ratio without black bars. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43731930/3445320) answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help!